# Android, after clicking button in the alert dialog, I want to do same function already used in the mainActivity

Tags: android, variables, alert

In the `requestDIalog.setPositiveButton`, I used setting function that I made outside of the mainActivity. This function is well working in side the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. 
And the code from DayDialog.lister~ startactivity(intent) is just the copy of the correct function in the onCreate. However, when I try to repeat same function in the alert dialog by copying entire code exactly, it shows error, saying, "proBar cannot be resolved to a variable"
How I can solve this error and repeat the same function? Please help.

```
private AlertDialog makeRequestDialog(CharSequence title, CharSequence message,
        CharSequence titleButtonYes, CharSequence titleButtonNo, CharSequence next) {

    AlertDialog.Builder requestDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    requestDialog.setTitle(title);
    requestDialog.setMessage(message);


    requestDialog.setPositiveButton(titleButtonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


            //From DayDialog.listener to StartActivity(intent), this section is already used in onCreation section with button setonclicklistener.

            DayDialog.listener = new onDaySelectedListener() {
                 public void onDaySelected(int days) {
                     option1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                     initOption.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);



                    currentDay = days; 
                     numWords=DayPreparation(currentDay);//It works!
                     index = 0;

                     setting(initOption,numWords,Button3,textView1,Words[index],proBar,Words,Means,index,currentDay,DayIndicator,false,option1);
                 }
             };

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DayDialog.class);
             startActivity(intent);


           }
    });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The error just indicates that there is no variable "proBar". If you could publish the rest of your code (at least the stuff containing the variable declarations).